# Interactive images/graphs like those used in BBC website

Tags: html, image, dynamic, graphics, interactive

I am aiming to built a website which will be quite interactive and vibrant. I am wondering how BBC often adds these interactive images and graphs to its website such as this:

[Link to a BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-15748696)

After some initial research I was told that they use HTML 5 but I am not sure if its correct. It seems so flow less just as if its Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular visualization you're showing can be efficiently done with [D3](http://d3js.org/) and in particular, this popular kind of diagram called ["Chord Diagram"](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006)

D3 is especially aimed at interactive visualizations, and can be easier than pure javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to find what BBC has used ? or do you reckon they have used D3 as well ?

Comment: I thought they had actually used D3, but it seems like entirely coded in javascript. I am not entirely sure though. Still, the easiest way to reproduce it would be with D3 ;)